# Java - Before a certain month of every year

Tags: java, date

How could I code a method that will allow a number to be added to another number before a certain month of each year? For example, I would like to be able to have a maximum deposit amount per year in a bank, and then the next year the max deposit amount starts again.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you want a method that is triggered at a certain time each year, if the program is running? Or are you trying to calculate dates or numbers of days?

Comment: I would like to be able to have a maximum deposit amount per year in a bank. Then the next year the max deposit amount starts again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, what I think you need is a bounds check, and a flag for whether or not the adjustment has happened yet.

So, in you deposit method, you would check whether or not the current date is before or after the date on which the max amount resets.  If it is after, and you have not reset yet this year, reset.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like

```
private static final double YEARLY_MAXIMUM = 100000;

void deposit(double amount) {
    if (yearLastUpdated != thisYear) {
        amountLeftForDeposit = YEARLY_MAXIMUM;
        yearLastUpdated = thisYear;
    }
    /* ... Code for deposit, checking that we're not busting this year's limit. */
}
```

You'll have to take care of persistence for amountLeftForDeposit and yearLastUpdated. I think you can get thisYear easily through the Date class.

Comment: If there's going to be more than one depositers at a time (let's say: bank and the account owner), the method (or a part of it) most certainly needs to be synchronized against some lock.. Otherwise (in theory) two threads could access the same method concurrently and YEARLY_MAXIMUM could be exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to M. Joanis's answer (see my comment):

I'm assuming, the wrapping type is Account or similar.. something that depicts a banking account. Then your deposit method would be synchronized as follows;

```
void deposit(double amount) {
    synchronized(this /* Account class instance */) {

    }
}
```

Synchronization protects you from concurrent access caused problems. People are most pedantic of their money..